# SQL Insert script Tuning

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me to tune this SQL? I have tried to insert into table but it is long running from past 23 hours.

```
insert into table_New
    select 
        A.date,
        A.id,
        A.date2,
        A.Region,
        A.District
        A.store,
        CNT1,
        CNT2,
        CNT3
    from
        table1 A 
    join
        table2 B on A.date = B.date
                 and A.date2 = B.date2
    join
        table3 C on A.date = C.date and A.date2 = C.date2
```

Note: each table is having 3lacks records.

Comment: Try to put indexes on `a (date, date2)`, `b (date, date2)` and `c (date, date2)`.

Comment: If you have set up indexes on `table_New`, you might also want to disable the indexes for `table_New`  during the insert operation and enable them afterwards. Otherwise every row insert gets more and more expensive. For a large number of records, it sometimes better to do a re-indexing afterwards.